# Merge three tables into one table, EXCEL POWERQUERY

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel, vba, powerquery

Or with SQL, whatever needs. 
I have three sheets(North, South, West) inside each table with columns DATE, REP, UNIT,NORTH(south west). I have data in rows like, 7/11/16, SMITH,FBI,$38.50 in sheet NOrth, and then in sheet West, 7/11/16,SMITH,FBI,$5.00. How to union or merge this kind of data? I tried with:

```
SELECT *from North$
Unon all
SELECT *from South$
Union all
Select *from West$
```

But, i only get append data. Those three tables have 47rows, i want those same rows in North and West to be joined in one row in new table!

Can i upload workbook? and how?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you need to give us some way of relating records from each of the tables.  Specifically, I think a join is along the lines of what you want, but there needs to be a _relation_ in order to do this.

Comment: What was the error?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Power Query Merge command to join the rows from North and West.  You haven't indicated what columns to join on but I'm sure you'll figure it out.  The Merge popup window is quite helpful.

You haven't said what your requirements are for South - possibly a 2nd Merge?

Comment: Date, Rep, Unit are same columns on all sheets. Only difference is North column, South column and West. I think my question is impossible.  Only solution is append through sql or PowerQuery :(

Comment: I'm confused - append will add rows, but you said "i want those same rows in North and West to be joined in one row in new table"?  In PQ that is a Merge.  You can add multiple Merge steps to join multiple tables. You can join on multiple columns - just select them in the Merge window.

Comment: Date, Rep, Unit, they have different rows, only few rows are the same. Those few rows i waant to be merged into one :)

Comment: I still cant follow your logic.  You seem to be plucking random values from different rows.

Comment: They aren't random. They must have same row values for attributes(Date, Rep, Unit columns).

Comment: I still don't follow.  How does your first result row get a value of $30.25 for North, when there are 3 input rows with the same Date Rep and Unit, having 2 different North values? Max? First? Something else?

Comment: Because, english isn't my 1. language, i cannot explain ... There is uploaded workbbok...    If same Date, Rep, Unit, then first North, then from South and then West.

Comment: So ... why do you not take the North value from the other rows?

Comment: I'll repeat: only few rows has same Date, REp, Unit. I want those few rows to be the same(one row) in new sheet(May 1st DAVIS).  You are right, "plucking" is what i'm trying to accomplish, if that's possible in excel :) But, hey, I'm fine with power query Append, for now. Please, dear Super Duper Excel Master User-reader, check my other questions: Comma decimal separator turns into dot(decimal point) after Print code